# Assign multiple source IPs to ALB rule via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to whitelist list of IPs for a certain path in our ALB using terraform. Terraform AWS provider is already working on alllowing multiple source-ip in configuration. Its not merged yet I have following configuration

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "forwarding_rule_http" {
    listener_arn = "${aws_alb_listener.http.arn}"
    priority     = 10

    action {
        type             = "forward"
        target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.main.id}"
    }

    condition {
        field  = "path-pattern"
        values = ["/path"]
    }

    condition {
        count  = "${length(var.source_ips)}"
        field  = "source-ip"
        values = ["${element(var.source_ips, count.index)}"]
    }
}
```

Here source-ip is a list and its an OR condition 
When i try to run it it says `count.index` is undefined 
Is there any workaround for this in TF?

Comment: I do not see `source-ip` as an allowed argument for `field` in the doc: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb_listener_rule.html

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have answered my question with appropriate links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Provider needs an update to support new ALB rules in Terraform
Its in progress and issue is already reported on GitHub

1. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8266
2. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8126